# Can anyone point me at an 802.11n range extender?

Tags: networking, wifi, 802.1

The closest google's getting me is this [question](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/expert/KnowledgebaseAnswer/0,289625,sid7_gci1325160,00.html) here, but the answer (presumably "none, run a wire") is behind a paywall.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one that plugs into your router use this one.
http://www.radiolabs.com/products/wireless/wireless-range-extender.php

I have this one and it is awesome. Easily 2.5x longer range and stronger signal. We use it to send Wi-Fi about 1/4 mile down a trail at my camp.

This one goes on the device receiving the signal instead of sending
http://www.radiolabs.com/products/wireless/802.11n-amplifier.php

I have no experience with this product, but I like the radio labs guys. Solid people there.

Comment: I'd like to be able to push my signal out to some other buildings on the property -- the first device looks like it'd work like a champ.  I may have to try it even though it's only 'g' -- I don't see an 802.11n equivalent on their site.

Comment: this is true, I would definalty put a call into the Radio labs guys and see what they say. They have always given me a money-back deal and I have taken them up on it when I got something that did not work the way I thought it would. There number is (877) 575-3700.

Comment: This might prove useful, its an 'n' mimo inline antenna amp for just a little more than the above product -> http://www.radiolabs.com/products/wireless/802.11n-amplifier.php

Comment: I agree drgncabe, that does look like it might do what Niniki wants. On either the recieving, sending, or heck both ends if he feels like it. Nice find.

Answer (score 0):

I use the one from linksys [here](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=1533895&CatId=4026). You can also get it at bestbuy. What router are you using though?

Comment: Appears to be 'g' not 'n' =x